# My first controller in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

I'm new of Symfony framework. I tried this simple code without any result. 
That's the server response:

> No route found for "GET /lucky/number" 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
>   1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »

I don't now why the Default controller use the annotation and I can see the homepage of my Symfony application.

Comment: Are you accessing to `/app_dev.php/lucky/number`? If you don't, you would need to clear the cache of the production environment: `$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`.

Comment: another thing: have you [imported the routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to import your annotation routes. Symfony will scan locations you mention in `app/config/routing.yml`.

```
# app/config/routing.yml
lucky:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

See [Symfony docs for more details](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation)

Also try clearing the cache, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an important part of the route and its name:

```
/**
* @Route("/lucky/number", name="lucky_number")
*/
```

More information: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html