# My first Symfony 2.4 component controller inside OpenEMR

Tags: php, symfony, components

I am building inside an existing application OpenEMR. I am trying to lay the foundation to build a report. I followed the instructions in this tutorial.

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/page_creation.html#creating-a-page-route-and-controller

While writing this request for help. I found this answer.

[My first controller in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859987/my-first-controller-in-symfony)

I added the suggested routing.yml to the config of the program and the error did not change. It is still generating this error.

```
 [11-Oct-2019 08:23:43 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: 
  Class 'OpenEMR\Finance\Reports\financialSummaryByInsurance' not found in 
   C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\mindfulemr4\interface\reports\insurance.php:5
    Stack trace:#0 {main} thrown in C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\mindfulemr4\interface\reports\insurance.php on line 5
```

So, the steps that I have taken are these. I edited the composer.json to add the namespace. I reloaded composer using the dumpautoloader -o after adding middle line below.

```
        "OpenEMR\\Billing\\" : "library/billing/src",
        "OpenEMR\\Finance\\Reports\\" : "library/financialReports/src",
        "OpenEMR\\Pdf\\" : "library/pdf/src",
```

I installed the routing component using

```
   composer require symfony/routing 2.4
```

I built the controller not using the word controller financialSummaryByInsurance using PHPStorm to assist in the naming and creation of the class.

```
    namespace OpenEMR\Finance\Reports;   //This will function as my controller event though not named controller

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing;                          //Making use of Symfony routing

    class financialSummaryByInsurance                      //Class controller name without the word controller
    {
        public function insurancepaid()
        {
            /**
             * @Route("/library/financialReports/src/financialSummaryByInsurance/insurancepaid", name = "insurancepaid")
             */
            return new Response("insurance data here my first controller from scratch"  );
        }

    }
```

Then, I thought to build a page to call the controller to display the information from the controller. The file is named insurance.php and the contents are.

```
    use OpenEMR\Finance\Reports\financialSummaryByInsurance;

    $show = new financialSummaryByInsurance;

    echo $show->insurancepaid();
```

PHPStorm was able to find and suggest each component in the insurance.php file. That is why I am confused as to the error message in the error log.  I must be missing something in getting this frame off the ground floor.

Comment: Where do you have your "require vendor/autoload.php" line?

Comment: The name of the controller class needs to have the Word 'Controller' at the end of it.

Comment: Can you confirm that the class `financialSummaryByInsurance` is located in `library/financialReports/src/financialSummaryByInsurance.php`? If not, this might be the cause for your `Class ... not found` error. If it is, make sure that autoloading in composer is updated, e.g. using `composer dump-autoload` as suggested in the answer from Theva

Comment: @dbrumann Pretty sure they are trying to do something standalone and that they have not actually required the autoload.php file at all.  Too bad they went dark.

Comment: Yes, the library/financialReports/src/financialSummaryByInsurance.php is in that folder. I checked the spelling of both twice. I found one misspelling.

Comment: I always run the autoload dump command when I am adding new classes.

Comment: I figured it out. It was the camel case. I had to capitalize the first letter of the file name and the first letter of the class. Something simple.

Answer (score 1):

it seems **class not found** error.

try to execute 
`composer dump-autoload` to re-generate the autoload file

and I see your routing class is not right one, it should be this

`use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;`

ref: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/controller.html

Comment: This did not solve the issue. I did put it in just to see what would happen. No joy.

Comment: Can you try modify this line in your composer.json as "psr-4": {
    "": "src/"
}, and then run composer dump-autoload

Comment: Theva -- I figured it out. It was the camel case. I had to capitalize the first letter of the file name and the first letter of the class. Something simple.

Answer (score 0):

To display the page returned from your controller `financialSummaryByInsurance`, you **must** call it with an HTTP request matching the `insurancepaid` route, you defined.

A controller is simply a PHP class and won't display you an html page if you instantiate it.

If you do a call on `GET http://yourdomain/library/financialReports/src/financialSummaryByInsurance/insurancepaid` (<-- this is a strange route path definition BTW) you should have your code return you an HTML response.